# Editing HTML file online from ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET website that is a panel for managing and sending e-mails. I want people to have an editor to changed what is in the template itself (which is writing in plain HTML.) in withing my site.

But, I don't want them to see the HTML. I just need them to edit the text and not touch the CSS/HTML to not destroy the look of it. Any tips or solutions that any one may know?

Comment: best solution is use "tinymce" **http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php** OR **Ajax Html Editor** for achieving this task

Comment: Why when you try to see the source or when you subiet it shows it with no html tag, any one?

Comment: Can any one please tell me? i am wating for days now, please.

Answer (score 1):

Use a free RichTextBox control in your project. You can find many open source or free controls out there.

Here's an example

http://www.freetextbox.com/

In this [website](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=1973) you could find a list of controls that you could use.

Comment: Vote and accept the answer if it was helpful and answered your question!

Comment: When i try to subit in the demo website, it shows it with no html tag, have any idea why?

Comment: Which demo website? and which control did you use?

Comment: http://www.freetextbox.com/demos/ , no matter which one, <html> is deleted and some other things when you try to save your data.

Comment: What other thing? Show your input and output and which control you use. Otherwise how can I say what's happening?

Comment: No Matter which html you put inside the textbox editor, you get it wtihout your <html> tag, <head> tag and <body> tag. how any idea ?

Comment: I am guessing you dont have any answer to me after more then a week wating?

Comment: That's how rich text editors behave. Isn't that your requirement?

Comment: No, i need to keep the html tag, beacuse if not its gets all wired and stop working

Comment: In your question you say "But, I don't want them to see the HTML". So I answered accordingly. Not sure what you are after

Comment: When you edit your html, you cant see the html, thats true. but, when i try to save it into an txt file, the <Html> teg and the <body> tag, is gone.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Ajax "HTMLEditior" or "HTMLEditiorExtender" for this
>   purpose
>
> For what is HTMLEditor and how to use it follow this link
>   [HTML Editor (AJAX Tool Kit)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/ajax-htmleditorextender/)

Answer (score 0):

Check [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) which has lot of editing features and your users can do almost everything. Also it supports inline editing.

Comment: this should be a comment - Not an answer .